# Installing PKCS 12 certificate in Android without password prompt?

Tags: android, certificate, keychain, pkcs#12

In Android , when adding a PKCS12 or pfx certificate to keychain; is there a way to provide the password programatically?

My app will download the PKCS12 cert when the user logs in and all subsequent calls need that cert to be sent back for authorization. I can generate its password in client side so while installing the cert with `KeyChain.createInstallIntent();` is there a way to send password along with that intent (without user entering the password)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I also need this information, but so far it seems that the Android OS will not let you install any user certification without having the user approve the install.